# How to query another collection per document in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relationship

Sorry the title isn't really clear, I was struggling a bit with it.

I'm trying to get posts from all a user's followers using thier IDs

```
PostModel.find({ author: { $in: arr } }).limit(150).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).exec();
```

and get the top comments ***(determined by the number of likes)*** for each post, the schema for comments is below

> Comment Schema

```
const commentSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    parentPost: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}, // Post a user is commenting on
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    likedBy: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});
```

Most of possible solutions I've come across has to do with agreggation but I'm not sure how to apply that here or if it's applicable, please how do I go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite applicable with `$lookup` stage in aggregation: [Perform a Single Equality Join with `$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#perform-a-single-equality-join-with-lookup)